# Enhance FastifyAdapter with option to normalize the request and response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, fastify

I was able to find a way to normalize the request and response in a `fastify` `onrequest hook`, so that middleware written for `express`, like `swagger-stats`, can be used with `fastify`.

I was wondering if there would be any interest in me adding this as an option to the `FastifyAdapter`, so that others can benefit from it? The thought is if this option is turned on, then in the constructor the `onrequest hook` will be added to the `fastify` instance.

Comment: Hi Eric, welcome to Stackoverflow! :-) Your request is better suited as an issue and/or pull request on the github repo, https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/new. I'm sure your contribution will be welcomed. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. After consideration I will make a new **fastify** **plugin**, and publish it, so that the community can choose to use it or not.

Answer (score 0):

The OP actually published the desired behavior as a [fastify plugin](https://github.com/ericrglass/fastify-normalize-request-reply).

You can install it via npm:

```
npm install --save fastify-normalize-request-reply
```

and then register it as a plugin with:

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-normalize-request-reply'));
```